# How to change element in pathData of android vector element?

Tags: android, vector

I have circle with inner circle.

How to delete inner circle?

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M12,2C5.47,2 2,6.47 2,12s4.47,10 10,10 10,-4.47 10,-10S17.53,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.41,0 -8,-3.59 -8,-8s3.59,-8 8,-8 8,3.59 8,8 -3.59,8 -8,8z"/>
</vector>
```

[image]